# Apache + Node.js + mod_proxy. Getting forwarded to https and app is not working

Tags: node.js, apache, mod-proxy

Problem: My Node-app is running on http://localhost:3000/, but mod-proxy is redirecting my traffic to https://localhost:3000/ and the app is not working giving me a "Site cant be reached" error

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin info@node-example.com
    ServerName  node-example.com
    ServerAlias www.node-example.com

    ProxyRequests off

    <Proxy *>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    <Location />
            ProxyPass http://localhost:3000/
            ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:3000/
    </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your config file will redirect www.node-example.com to *localhost:3000 on the server machine*.

Do you own *node-example.com*?

Comment: it is redirecting to HTTPS and my app is configured to run on HTTP and im using a free DNS

Comment: why not just make your app use https?  it's better anyway

Comment: I just did that by using self signed certificate (openssl) but now my server is bugged and I'm getting 502 proxy error. Where are all the people who use mod_proxy for nodejs ? please help me

Comment: I suspect it is not mod_proxy that is forcing the HTTPS.  Mod proxy in this case would simply be redirecting traffic from `node-example.com` to get information from the machine `localhost:8000`